# How to Generate same result for same input when using IDataProtectionProvider

Tags: c#, encryption, .net-core

I'm going to use IDataProtectionProvider in asp.netcore application.
I've done all related configuration at Startup.cs as below:

```
        services.AddDataProtection()
                .SetApplicationName("my-app")
                .PersistKeysToFileSystem(new DirectoryInfo(@"\keys"))
                .UseCryptographicAlgorithms(
                    new AuthenticatedEncryptorConfiguration()
                    {
                        EncryptionAlgorithm = EncryptionAlgorithm.AES_256_CBC,
                        ValidationAlgorithm = ValidationAlgorithm.HMACSHA256
                    });
```

and I'm using that like this:

```
    public WeatherForecastController(IDataProtectionProvider dataProtectionProvider)
    {
        this.dataProtectionProvider = dataProtectionProvider;
    }

    [HttpGet]
    public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
    {
        var protector = dataProtectionProvider.CreateProtector("weather");
        var firstEncrypted = protector.Protect("hello");
        var secondEncrypted = protector.Protect("hello");
        ...
    }
```

but firstEncrypted and secondEncrypted aren't equal.
I'll search on encrypted values and I need to generate same result for fixed input.

I don't know what should i do, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

To get the same encryption string here is not possible. This is a security feature, same input, always different hash.
The `IDataProtectionProvider` uses Salting, you can find for information on that concept here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Salt_(cryptography)
Details on the encryption details can be found here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/authenticated-encryption-details?view=aspnetcore-8.0